# numpy maximum reduce error for pandas series and int

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

`np.maximum.reduce(lst)` has different behavior from `functools.reduce(np.maximum, lst)` and also different behavior from `np.maximum` itself, when one of the elements in the list is a number (e.g. int) instead of an array/pandas Series.

### `np.maximum.reduce`

on one hand,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 3, 2]})

np.maximum.reduce([df['a'], 2])
```

The last line gives the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

### `np.maximum`

on the other hand,

```
np.maximum(df['a'], 2)
```

yields the expected output

```
0    2
1    3
2    2
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

### `reduce(np.maximum)`

on a third hand,

```
reduce(np.maximum, [df['a'], 2])
```

also yields the expected output

```
0    2
1    3
2    2
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

### Versions used

pandas version: 1.2.5
numpy version: 1.19.5
python: 3.7.9

Comment: `np.maximum` will broadcast automatically, but `np.maximum.reduce` will not. It is equivalent to `np.max` and expects a regular array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the docs for [`ufunc.reduce`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html)

> `.reduce(array, axis=0, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False, initial=<no value>, where=True)`
>
> Reduces array’s dimension by one, by applying ufunc along one axis.

`[df['a'], 2]` is not an array with a well-defined 0th axis. I’m not sure how this could work? The other operations are clear element-wise max operations which will operate on each argument after broadcasting against each other but numpy ufunc reduction operates on a single array.

Comment: I see. Guess I was expecting the broadcasting behavior to carry over like in `functools.reduce`. But seems like it may be using a different implementation under the hood, skipping the broadcasting step.

Comment: It’s definitely a different implementation, but it’s also just a different operation. They have the same words in them but one is for an iterable and the other for an axis of a single array. They’re not interchangeable at all.

Comment: great point, guess only `functools.reduce` fits my use case.

Comment: I expect np.maximum called with many numpy or pandas args would be faster than wrapping it in functools.reduce. If you only have two arguments than the reduce step isn’t needed.

Comment: Definitely. Though `np.maximum` taking only 2 args is a bit limiting. In a more generic use case with an arbitrary number of args, and the number of args depends on usage at run time, it's tricky.

Comment: Oops my bad! I forgot maximum only accepted two args. You’re totally right.